# how to display top selling product of the particular category magento

Tags: magento

I want to display top selling/best selling of the particular parent categories in magento. I have some parent categories such as flowers, cakes, etc. When i go to flower i just want to show best selling product from flower in cakes from cakes and so on.

Comment: use this link : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-bestselling-products-by-category-and-date-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use following code:-
public function getBestSellersCollection($numDays = 60, $categoryId)
{

                $todayDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
                                $fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now -'.$numDays.' days'));

                                $_bestSellersCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                ->addOrderedQty()
                                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                                ->addCategoryFilter($categoryId)
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('date' => true, 'from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $todayDate))
                                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
                                $bestsoldids = Array();
                                foreach($_bestSellersCollection as $col){
                                                $bestsoldids[] = $col->getData('entity_id');
                                }
                                return $bestsoldids;
    }
```

Comment: Anyone help, how can i get this report from my codeigniter.